# Is it correct to skip the second article “the” while writing about the object placement?

Tags: grammar, articles

Which of the following is correct?

(...) an element will be placed **on the right or left side** of a container (...)

(...) an element will be placed **on the right or on the left side** of a container (...)

I was trying to find grammar rules related to this but without success.

Comment: This is purely a stylistic choice. Neither one is incorrect.

Comment: You can look here [Modern Legal Usage](https://books.google.ru/books?id=35dZpfMmxqsC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=omitting+repeated+article&source=bl&ots=kbpWTGneG8&sig=CPvadf-SkqN1kA83PmkEhHnz_Fk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR5_aElPDXAhVLG5oKHX2IAUwQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=omitting%20repeated%20article&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

**Articles**, **prepositions**, **adjectives** and even **nouns** and **verbs** are often omitted in repeating sections. As **J.R.** commented - this is a purely a stylistic choice. However, there is a "**but**" to it.

In order to avoid ambiguity often these words aren't omitted *(especially when we are speaking of adjectives and nouns)*. Also, omitting repeated articles can lead to misunderstanding; the two things can be rendered as a single combination whereas keeping the article will ensure *(emphasise)* that the two things are separate.

With adjectives this may lead to ambiguity, for instance: "**I have a black book and pencil**" may mean that both the book and the pencil are black. To avoid such things you can either repeat the article or reorder the list *(this may be handy with more than two things especially)*: "**I have a black book and a pencil**" or "**I have a pencil and a black book**" *(here the article can't be omitted)*.

With prepositions it is often best to include the repeating preposition to help the reader follow the structure of your sentence *(especially if it is a long and complex sentence)*. Also repeating a preposition before each noun is done for the sake of emphasis or to mark opposition and difference. Notice, you can't omit prepositions that have different meaning.

Anyway, since in English much depends on the context it is better to view each example separately. I recommend you take a look at this reference **[A Guide to Elliptical Constructions](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/a-guide-to-elliptical-constructions/)**.